# How to make collidable moving platform using KinematicBody2D?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot3

I'm trying to make a levitating platform using `KinematicBody2D` and when my character (also `KinematicBody2D`) falls on top the platform stops moving

[image]

Code for the platform:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var levitation_speed: float = 1000
var _velocity: Vector2

# for simplicity sake I've only shown the platform moving up
func _physics_process(delta):
    _velocity += levitation_speed * delta * Vector2.UP
    _velocity = move_and_slide(_velocity)
```

code for the player:

```
extends KinematicBody2D
class_name Humanoid

var velocity:Vector2
export var gravity_speed=3500
export var jump_speed=-1800
export var horizontal_speed=600

func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction=Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    velocity.x=horizontal_speed * direction
    
    if(is_on_floor()):
        if(Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up")):
            velocity.y+=jump_speed
    
    velocity.y += gravity_speed * delta
    velocity=move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
```

How do I make the player move along the platform no matter the direction it moves in? If this is not possible with `KinematicBody2D` I'm open to using `RigidBody2D`

**Note:** I'm intentionally using `_physics_process()` & not `AnimationPlayer` or `Tween` so if you suggest a work around please involve it

---

#### Edit:

Based on the provided answer by @Theraot it sort of works when the player falls on top of platform but fails when the player tries to enter from below as such:

[image]

as any good platform in a game, the player should be able to pass through it from underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `move_and_slide_with_snap` instead of `move_and_slide` on the **player**, should keep it snap to the ground when the ground is moving.

It needs an snap vector, which you can imagine as a ray that checks for the platform.

The code would be like this:

```
velocity=move_and_slide_with_snap(velocity, Vector2.DOWN, Vector2.UP)
```

However, after testing this didn't solve the problem at hand.

---

**`global_position`**

What we can do is move the **platoform** without `move_and_slide` nor `move_and_slide_with_snap`, but by changing its `global_position` instead, like this:

```
global_position += _velocity * delta
```

This means that the platform will move ignoring any obstacles (to be clear: it will go through static obstacles), however it can still push the player.

This solution also allows to enable `motion/sync_to_physics` however that is not necesary since we would be moving in `_physics_process`.

---

**`one_way_collision`**

I found another way: We can set `one_way_collision` to `true` on the collider of the player.

The player and platform can then still use `move_and_slide` or `move_and_slide_with_snap` and both will collide with static obstacles.

Thus this solution does not require any code change.

Comment: nope this has no effect for moving the player upwards on the platform

Comment: @M.R.M. Oh, wrote that wrong. Fixing it. Edit: try the modified version.

Comment: `move_and_slide_with_snap` doesn't work
you can try to replicate the code I've given, the platform still fails to raise the player up

Comment: This works but one of the reasons I was using `_physics_process` was to ensure the platform does collide with static obstacles, is there any way to add that? or will I have to switch to rigidbody2D? Edit: think of the platform as more of a skateboard

Comment: Also I would recommend enabling `motion/sync_to_physics` since if it is kept disabled the player seems to "go into" the platform as it is moving up

Comment: @M.R.M. `one_way_collision` seems to work with both platform and player using `move_and_slide`. I'm adding it to the answer. Edit: done.

Comment: this kinda works but it has it's flaws, please check the edit in the question

Comment: @M.R.M. That is a different problem. The solution I've thought for that is using an `Area2D` that extends slightly down from the platform, and use it to detect the player, when the player enters the area (`"body_entered"`), it can add the player to the exclusions of the platform (in the platform call `add_collision_exception_with` passing the player), and when it leaves it (`"body_exited"`) can remove it from the exclusions so the player can land on top of it (call `remove_collision_exception_with` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the perfect platform which uses `_physics_process(delta)`

Features:

1. Doesn't squish the player
2. Allows player jump on it
3. Allows player to pass from underneath it
4. Platform collides with the world!

Structure:

[image]

Platform code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var base = $Base
onready var base_offset=global_position - base.global_position
var velocity:Vector2

func _physics_process(delta):

    # manipulate velocity
    ...
    
    velocity=move_and_slide(velocity)
    base.global_position=self.global_position - base_offset
```

In this demo the platform is moving in a circular direction but is obstructed by obstacles:

[image]

demo platform code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var base = $Base
onready var base_offset=global_position - base.global_position
export var radius: float = 400
export var angular_speed: float = 0.5

var angle: float = 0
onready var initial_position: Vector2 = global_position

func _physics_process(delta):
    angle += angular_speed * delta
    
    var new_x = initial_position.x + radius * cos(angle)
    var new_y = initial_position.y + radius * sin(angle)
    var velocity = Vector2(new_x, new_y) - global_position
    
    move_and_slide(velocity)
    
    base.global_position=self.global_position - base_offset
```